# In Azure Stream Analytics SQL, how do I pass the result of a subquery to a GeoJSON Create function?

Tags: geojson, spatial, azure-stream-analytics

I'm trying to use Stream Analytics to create spatial data from a bunch of objects written to Blob Storage. I'm in the process of creating a Stream Analytics job, and I've added my blob collection as an input. The blobs are of a regular structure and contain latitude and longitude properties.

I want to group the incoming records by originating sensor (this is identified by a string which is effectively a primary key) and turn the set of coordinates for each group into a GeoJSON LineString.

I have a query along the lines of:

```
WITH points AS (
SELECT GeoJSON.CreatePoint(longitude, latitude) as point, sensorId, time
FROM SensorEvents)
SELECT GeoJSON.CreateLineString(???)
INTO youroutputalias
FROM SensorEvents
```

What do I have to pass to `GeoJSON.CreateLineString` to get it to take a set of points and make that into a single LineString?

Answer (score 0):

1-  Is this blob information a reference data, or is this going to mutate with time?

2-  If this mutates, you'll need to specify a time boundary where this aggregation is going to happen. ASA will aggregate over time and group by ID, you cannot aggregate by ID only. ASA is a temporal engine.

CreateLineString needs a static list of points to construct the object, here we have a dynamic number of points on each call to CreateLineString.

•   If the blob data is dynamic the best option would be to use UDF to aggregate by time then group by ID and have the UDF function create the geojson linestring object.

•   If the blob is static the best option would be to blob the geojson and just pass it to ASA as a field.